# socket bind failed when WiFi is OFF

Tags: java, android, sockets, service, network-programming

I built an application which has a service and it contains sockets to receive messages in LAN.It work fine when WiFi is ON, but when I start the application  with WiFi OFF state it gives an error of socket bind failed and it don't work even if I turn the WiFi ON.

Is there any way to get notified in the app when the WiFi is turned on so that I can start that particular service again, or any other method to bind the socket so that it may bind correctly with the WiFi OFF state.
My current code is:

```
socket = new DatagramSocket(port, broadcastIP);

        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(recvBuf, recvBuf.length);

        socket.receive(packet);
```

Comment: So was my response useful for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If WiFi is OFF you are probably getting a SocketException when creating the DatagramSocket instance because the socket cannot be bound to the IP address passed. Moreover, if the network interface is down it doesn't have any IP address.

Maybe you should ask first for the network interfaces in your device and then check the status of each interface. If the interface is up then you get the IP address and then you can create a socket bound to it.

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nets = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();

for (NetworkInterface netIf : Collections.list(nets))
{
    System.out.println("Display name: " + netIf.getDisplayName());
    System.out.println("Name: " + netIf.getName());

    if (netIf.isUp()) //Is the interface up
    {
        Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddresses = netIf.getInetAddresses();

        for (InetAddress inetAddress : Collections.list(inetAddresses))
        {
            System.out.println("InetAddress: " + inetAddress);
        }
    }
}
```

Look here: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/retrieving.html
and here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html